# MVC 4 auto fill windows user name

Tags: asp.net, windows, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication

I am working on mix authentication mode in ASP.NET MVC 4, and I want the Windows username to be auto filled in my textbox. I have used  `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;` and it is working fine on local, but when i am executing it on the server, "Default AppPool " is coming in username textbox.

my cshtml code --

```
@model TMVCRepository.Models.ActivedirectoryModels
  @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Active directory authentication";

  }
 @{

     string UserIDwindows = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;

    string[] Usernameis = UserIDwindows.Split('\\');


    if (ViewData["Error"] != "" && ViewData["Error"] != null)
    {
        string res = ViewData["Error"].ToString();

    <span style="color: red; font-size: 14px;">

        @res
    </span>

        ViewData["Error"] = null;



    }


}

@using (Html.BeginForm("index", "Activedirectory"))
{ 


    <h2>ENTER YOUR NETWORK / SYSTEM LOGIN CREDENTIALS


    </h2>


    <table width="100%">

        <tr>

            <td>

                @Html.LabelFor(a => a.UserID)

            </td>

        </tr>

        <tr>

            <td>

                @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.UserID, new { @Value = Usernameis[1] })
                @*   @Html.TextBox(UserID,)*@

                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.UserID)

            </td>

        </tr>

        <tr>

            <td>

                @Html.LabelFor(a => a.Password)

            </td>

        </tr>

        <tr>

            <td>

                @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Password)

                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.Password)

            </td>

        </tr>

        <tr>

            <td>

                @Html.LabelFor(a => a.DomainName)

            </td>

        </tr>

        <tr>

            <td>

                @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.DomainName)

                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.DomainName)

            </td>

        </tr>


        <tr>

            <td colspan="2">

                <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" />



            </td>

        </tr>

    </table>   

}

    my controller.

    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using TMVCRepository.Models;
    using Telerik.Web.Mvc;
    using System.DirectoryServices;
    using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
    using System.Web.Security;
    using TMVCRepository.DataAccessLayer;

      namespace TMVCRepository.Controllers
    {
        public class ActivedirectoryController : Controller
        {

            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                return View();
            }





            [HttpPost]

            public ActionResult index(ActivedirectoryModels UC)
            {


                if (ModelState.IsValid) 
                {


                    string userid = Request.Form["UserID"];
                    string password = Request.Form["Password"];
                    string domainname = Request.Form["DomainName"];


                    return RedirectToAction("submit",
                                "Activedirectory",
                                new { userid = userid, password = password, 
      domainname = domainname });

                }

                else
                {

                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Error in Viewing data");

                    return View();

                }

            }
            public ActionResult submit(string userid, string password, string 
      domainname)
            {
                string group1 = null;
                string group2 = null;
                string group3 = null;
                string group4 = null;
                string group5 = null;


                try
                {
                    bool value = IsAuthenticated(domainname, userid, password);


                    if (value == true)
                    {
                        DBclass obj1 = new DBclass();
                        string result = obj1.chkuserentry(userid);
                        if (result == "Yes")
                        {
                           FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userid, true);

                            // begin


                         using (var context1 = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainname))
                            {
                                if(userid!="testadmin")
                                {
                                using (var exuser = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context1, userid))
                                {
                                    var groups = exuser.GetGroups();

                                string group_name = null;
                                foreach (object obj in groups)
                                {
                                    group_name += "~" + obj.ToString();

                                }

                                group_name = group_name.Replace("~Domain 
  Users","");


                                //oadd split code 

                                string[] strTemp = group_name.Split('~');


                                    for (int i = 0; i < strTemp.Length; i++)
                                    {

                                        if (i == 0)
                                        { group1 = strTemp[0]; }
                                        if (i == 1)
                                        { group2 = strTemp[1]; }
                                        if (i == 2)
                                        { group3 = strTemp[2]; }
                                        if (i == 3)
                                        { group4 = strTemp[3]; }
                                        if (i == 4)
                                        { group5 = strTemp[4]; }



                                    }



                                    if (group1 == null || group1 == "")
                                    { group1 = "N/A"; }
                                    if (group2 == null || group2 == "")
                                    { group2 = "N/A"; }
                                    if (group3 == null || group3 == "")
                                    { group3 = "N/A"; }
                                    if (group4 == null || group4 == "")
                                    { group4 = "N/A"; }
                                    if (group5 == null || group5 == "")
                                    { group5 = "N/A"; }



                                DBclass obj2 = new DBclass();


                                string result1 = obj1.Exist_user(userid, group1, 
 group2, group3, group4, group5);    



                            }
                        }

                    }

                        //end


                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

                    }

                    else
                    {

                        using (var context = new 
  PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainname))
                        {
                            using (var user = 
  UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, userid))
                            {

                                var groups = user.GetGroups();
                                string groupname = "";
                                foreach (object obj in groups)
                                {
                                    groupname += "~" + obj.ToString();

                                }



                                TempData["userid"] = userid;


                                TempData["Password"] = password;
                                TempData["Group"] = groupname;
                                return RedirectToAction("Register", "Account");

                            }
                        }

                    }


                }


                else
                {


                    return View("test");
                }








            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {


                return View("test");

            }



        }


        public bool IsAuthenticated(string srvr, string usr, string pwd)
        {

            bool authenticated = false;

            try
            {

        DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + srvr, usr + 
  "@" + srvr,pwd, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);


            }
            catch (DirectoryServicesCOMException cex)
            {

            }


            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //not authenticated due to some other exception [this is optional]
            }

            return authenticated;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the exact code you're using. As it stands, it's not possible to usefully answer your question.

Comment: i have include the code.plz go thru  it..

Comment: is there a way out  to develop a different application to retrieve windows user name and pass that user name it  to this present application ..???

Answer (score 0):

If the user is not logged in to your web application, how would you consider to obtain their username?

You can't.

The fact that it worked during development is because you're asking the *web server* under which user it runs, and the development server runs under the developer's account.

Comment: Is there a way out to develop a different application to retrieve windows user name and pass that user name it to this present application ..???

Comment: Well maybe if you write a browser plugin, but what problem are you trying to solve, really? If you use Windows Authentication then the browser will login your user automatically.

Answer (score 0):

To get auto authentication in Mixed authentication mode is this what you are asking ?
Then I may answer it as no , it is not possible or in other words never done practically

Comment: is there a way out to develop a different application to retrieve windows user name and pass that user name it to this present application ..???

Comment: Hey you cannot pass windows password to another application ,You can make Username to travel somehow